# ViewportControl and Images - how to avoid endless scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am coding a kind of map (for a very simple game) which is (for now) an image.
I want the user to be able to scroll the image around and resize it. 
I tried a lot around, and currently i am using the ViewportControl, and the XAML looks more or less like the following (see below).
I works as it does all i need - BUT the image itself can be scrolled within the ViewportControll without any boundaries. As a result the image scrolls away.

Question: is there any way to prevent the Viewportcontroll to scroll the image out of a specified region?

```
<ViewportControl x:Name="viewport" Height="600" Width="440">
            <Canvas x:Name="ParentCanvas" Background="Red" MaxHeight="600" MaxWidth="440">
            <Image x:Name="MapImage" Source="/Artwork/map.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.2,0.2" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="-200" Canvas.Top="-300" Width="1320" Height="1800">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
                <tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <tk:GestureListener  PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
                </tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Canvas>
        </ViewportControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing around i have a solution for my problem. 
The most important part is to add the **Bounds**-tag to the ViewportControl as you can see below.
The scrolling is then handled by the ViewportControl itself. The pinch-gesture must be done manually, but it is possible, because the events will reach the correct UI-Element (here: the image).
In the example below, i used the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to handle the event more easily.

```
<ViewportControl x:Name="viewportCtrl" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Bounds="0,0,1320,1800">
            <Canvas x:Name="ParentCanvas" Background="Red" Height="1000" Width="800">
                <Image x:Name="MapImage" Source="/Artwork/map.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.2,0.2" >
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
                <Canvas x:Name="BlueCanvas" Top="100" Left="200" Background="Blue" Height="180" Width="180"></Canvas>
                <tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <tk:GestureListener  PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
                </tk:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Canvas>
        </ViewportControl>
```